# How to retrieve manufacturer id?

Tags: magento2, post-data, manufacturer, id

How to retrieve manufacturer id?

```
$api = new maRest("www.host.com/magento/");     
$api->connect("user","xxxxxxx");
$manufacturers = array(
    "option" => array(
        'label' => "Sony",
    )
);
$manufacturer = $api->post("products/attributes/manufacturer/options", $manufacturers);
echo $manufacturer->id;
```

https://github.com/ezael/magento-2-api-made-easy

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 /*
  * Load product by product id
 */
$_productId = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID; 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);


/*
  * Get manufacturer id
*/
$_manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
```

hope this helps